# how to block youtube in the hosts file

Tags: macos, youtube, hosts

I know how to block websites in the host file and it works with others, but with YouTube i just can't get it to work. What am I missing?

```
127.0.0.1 youtube.com
127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com
```

Comment: well i want to block youtube and after applying these settings, running -flushcache and restarting youtube still isn't blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map `127.0.0.1` loopback address to youtube.com or others except `localhost` may cause some problems.

So map any unreachable IPv6 address is more better such like:

```
200:2:253d:369e::    youtube.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to flush the cache by running

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Also, the entries in the hosts file need to be DNS names, not URLs (meaning the last two lines are wrong).

Comment: did that, also restarted safari, still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the entire computer, not just Safari or flushing cache.